# Launch Daemon .plist missing. How to get it back?

Tags: macos, launchd, webcam, plist

My system is working fine (iMac running Mountain Lion), except that when I try to import video to iMovie using the built-in iSight camera I see a message "no camera connected". iSight works fine in Skype, photobooth, etc.

The solution to this, documented [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS2472), is to trash `com.apple.mio.VDCAssistant.plist` at the path `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/` and it's supposed to rebuild after a restart. But when I navigate to this path, the relevant file is just not there. Restart doesn't affect it, neither does logging in with a different user account. Repairing disk permissions doesn't help. I found a file named com.apple.**cmio**.VDCAssistant.plist at that location but only in a Time Machine backup - it's not present on my current system.

My main question is: does the absence of `com.apple.mio.VDCAssistant.plist` indicate a deeper problem that ought to be fixed? If not, I can live with not being able to import video directly to iMovie directly from the camera.

If it does indicate a deeper problem, I guess it's time to reinstall the OS. If that's the case, can I restore the system from a time machine backup or will this just reintroduce the original problem?

Thanks for reading - I'd really appreciate any input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Reinstalled the OS and the 'cmio' file is now there, though doesn't rebuild when moved. iSight still not recognised. The iSight issue must be a bug confined to older versions of iMovie, even though they're still supported by Mountain Lion. I'll use QuickTime to import the footage.